# Why StatsModels shows log likelyhood function decreases as the fit gets better?

Tags: regression, linear

I was going through https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html

and as you see from the example (the output of sm.OLS) Log-Likelihood increases as R-squared decreases.

Shouldn't Log-Likelihood and  R-squared increase together?

Shouldn't Log-Likelihood increase as your model fits better to the data?

Or am I wrong in thinking Log-Likelihood should increase as the model fit gets better.

Comment: Isn’t this a different dataset in each example?

Comment: R-Squared and Log likelihood are showing a inverse relationship in these examples.  Which is confusing me.

Comment: My point is that it doesn’t make sense to compare log likelihoods among different data sets.